# Lipschitz continuous dynamical system

Tags: dynamical-systems, lipschitz-functions

I stumbled upon the notion of a Lipschitz continuous dynamical system, and was wondering what this exactly meant. I guess it means that all solutions to (in my case the dynamical system is a set of ODE's) are Lipschitz continuous, but I wanted to be sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the right side in $\dot y=f(t,y)$ is Lipschitz-continuous in $y$. Then the uniqueness theorem applies (Picard-Lindelöf) and also numerical simulation will give meaningful results.

The solutions will be continuously differentiable, if the function $f$ is Lipschitz in all variables, then the solutions have (locally) Lipschitz continuous derivatives.